# In windows 8, my proxy server settings get enabled automatically, how do I turn this off?

Tags: networking, windows-8, proxy

I have a new laptop running windows 8, the proxy settings get enabled randomly and I can't use Internet explorer at that point.  I have to manually turn off the proxy each time.  I've gone through Internet options -> connections -> LAN settings -> advanced -> ( I delete everything in the boxes), I then get a popup saying "do you want to turn off the proxy connection", I select yes.

After restarting the computer it's fine for a day or two and all those delete settings reappear in the proxy server box. How can I turn them off?

Comment: Enabled randomly??  I'd make sure there isn't malware.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2777643

"How to configure proxy server settings in Windows 8"

What you had posted works fine in previous versions of Windows, you are most likely going to use the section: "How to configure proxy server settings through Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Protocol (WPAD)

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the very same odd behavior. Found out this only happened when [Fiddler 2](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) was running. After closing it the proxy was kept switched off.
So if you have any network monitoring tool which creates proxy, then close/remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact odd case, 
After a month of testing all possible solution, i finally got it today.

1. Checked my Event View (eventvwr) for any activity of the Proxy
   Setting.
2. Found that "af_proxy_cmd.exe" was the process keep changing my Proxy !
3. af_proxy_cmd.exe is one of the process used by Anchor Hotspot Shield
   VPN Tunnel Software.
4. After removing Hotspot Shield, my issue were resolved :)

So make sure that your VPN software do not touch the proxy setting